# Extracting single area with multiple layers from two different data sources

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv

I'm very new to GIS.

I am using ArcMap.  I have a state map of congressional districts from one data source.  From another data source, I have blank census tracts.  From yet a third data source (this one non-GIS data from a CSV file) I joined it to the census tracts, matching data to the census tracts.  So far it works great, I can create layers based on census data that matches these census tracts.  Here's the final issue:

I need a "clean" map of certain congressional districts, that shows the census tracts and all their layered data within just a single district.  If I try to clip a district, it is just the outline of the district.  The only solution I have come up with is to clip the district and carefully manually select ~20 census tracts, then I have to completely recreate all the layers to replicate my statewide map.  This would be insanely time consuming for all the districts I need to pull.  I also tried select by location but it just copied the district and ignored all the other data.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps export the joined tracts to a shapefile to make the attribute join permanent, then clip... If you use Union instead of clip then you can definition query each district by their unique identifier... the union result will have all the attributes of the districts, tracts and table. If you're making multiple maps you can use data driven pages to streamline the process.

Comment: Thank you... I'm not savvy enough to just try that quickly, but I will work on it.

Comment: Overlap operators are GIS bread-and-butter, take your time and do it twice (or more) to get it clear in your mind. Many (most) workflows in GIS include these operations. If there's a specific concept you have problems with don't be afraid to Google or post if you get no results (or more likely too many to read and evaluate).

Comment: I took a shot at it and already I understand a lot more due to reading up on Union.  I also discovered importing symbology, which will make this FAR easier.  Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> Perhaps export the joined tracts to a shapefile to make the attribute
>   join permanent, then clip... If you use Union instead of clip then you
>   can definition query each district by their unique identifier... the
>   union result will have all the attributes of the districts, tracts and
>   table. If you're making multiple maps you can use data driven pages to
>   streamline the process.